# export to CSV hangs with pgadmin4

Tags: macos, pgadmin-4

I want to export my query result as CSV file.

But this option is not working. When I press 'Download as CSV (F8)' button it looks like it is processing something but nothing happens after that. This is on Mozilla-60.6.1esr (64-bit) on MacOS

Comment: Please look at the console (F12) and post the actual error messages

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with latest version of pgAdmin4.

This issue has been fixed
Ref: https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/4071

Download: https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-macos/

Comment: Problem solved with latest version of pgadmin (4.4). Thank you very much.